# Date time sorting in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date

So I have a seemingly not so smart question but here goes,

```
10:00pm to 11:00pm
```

have a date time returned from the server in the above format.

I want to be able to sort it, but using `ORDER BY ASC` doesn't seem to work. It works on the iPhone but it doesn't work on Android.

Is it because of an SQLite database version?

How do I sort the time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you show is not a date time but a time interval.

This value is a string, and strings are compared lexicographically.
To ensure that your strings sort correctly, all fields must always have the same length (if not, `9:00` will be sorted *after* `10:00`; use `09:00` instead).
Furthermore, the `AM`/`PM` suffixes do not sort correctly in the first hour of the day; use a plain 24-hour format instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because the SQLite, but try to store time in sec, if you sort sec it will work. EX 1:05 = 65 sec.
Edit: if you want to display time in view, just convert it back to h:m:s
I think this will be the easiest way for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, Before storing in database convert the date into milis. Then you can get the sorted list from that. Then After getting sorted result you can again convert them to date.

For converting you can use SimpleDateFormat class. sample codes can be found in the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or you can see lots of examples out there

Answer (score 0):

You can sort date by using **Time Stamp**: Like: "yy MM dd hh:mm a" // here in your case hh:mma

Convert you time into Simple Date Format Like Below:

```
DateFormat simpleDateFordate = new SimpleDateFormat("yy MM dd");
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = simpleDateFordate.format(calender.getTime());
        System.out.println("date>>>>" + date);
        String time = "10:00pm";
        String stringDate = date + " " + time;

        DateFormat dateFormatdatewithTime = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yy MM dd hh:mma");
        Date dateinMili;
        try {
            dateinMili = dateFormatdatewithTime.parse(stringDate);
            String dateFinal = dateFormatdatewithTime.format(dateinMili.getTime());
            System.out.println("Final Date time>>>>"+dateFinal);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Store Mili Seconds into your data base or you can simply store your dateinSimpleFormat Date into your database.

After all this you can directly sort it by simple query like:
 SELECT * From Table_Name ORDER BY Column_Date ASC